# How Can I get values into html tags using Simple HTML Dom?

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

I am scraping some values from a table but I have problem to get values from data-odd ("odds" and "odds best betrate" as Class) into td tags.

I will post code:

```
<tr class="first-row">
    <td class="first-cell tl">
        <a href="../matchdetails.php?matchid=dGifTQkE" onclick="win(this.href, 560, 500, 0, 1); return false;">Kortrijk - St. Truiden</a>
    </td>
    <td class="result">
        <a href="../matchdetails.php?matchid=dGifTQkE" onclick="win(this.href, 560, 500, 0, 1); return false;">3:0</a>
    </td>
    <td class="odds best-betrate" **data-odd="1.72"**></td>
    <td class="odds" **data-odd="3.61"**></td>
    <td class="odds" **data-odd="4.76"**></td>
    <td class="last-cell nobr date">20.02.2016</td>
</tr>
<tr class="strong">
    <td class="first-cell tl">
        <a href="../matchdetails.php?matchid=ADWJ4sDD" onclick="win(this.href, 560, 500, 0, 1); return false;">Lokeren - Genk</a>
    </td>
    <td class="result">
        <a href="../matchdetails.php?matchid=ADWJ4sDD" onclick="win(this.href, 560, 500, 0, 1); return false;">0:0</a>
    </td>
    <td class="odds" **data-odd="3.11"**></td>
    <td class="odds best-betrate" **data-odd="3.31"**></td>
    <td class="odds" **data-odd="2.25"**></td>
    <td class="last-cell nobr date">20.02.2016</td>
</tr>
```

I know how I can get values between tags and I got them using Simple HTML Dom, but I really don't know how I can get values about "data-odd. In my code you can see bold values that I want to get.

Thanks :)

**EDIT:** Now I got this result (see picture below):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiYCH.jpg)

I want that values together the others values, example:

21.02.2016
Waasland-Beveren - Anderlecht 1:0 5.96 4.20 1.51

21.02.2016
Waregem - KV Mechelen 2:3 1.83 3.71 3.98

Thanks Again!

**EDIT2:**
This is my code:

```
    <?php
include('../simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/belgium/jupiler-league/results/');


foreach($html->find('td') as $e) {
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';

 }   


foreach( $html->find('td[data-odd]') as $td )
{
    echo $td->attr['data-odd'].PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

Comment: They are just HTML tag attributes, see [DOMElement::getAttribute()](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php)

Comment: HTML in example is **exactly** your HTML or asterisks are added by you to mark `data-odd`?

Comment: I added asterisk to mark which data I need to get. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `data-odd` is an attribute of node, so to retrieve its value with *simple_html_dom* you have to use this syntax:

```
foreach( $html->find('td[data-odd]') as $td )
{
    echo $td->attr['data-odd'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is almost perfect, but I need values together the others values.  I edited my first 'post, check it please :) Thanks

Comment: @marcellogabrielli really you don't know how to join values? It's depend of your html code, check it and change it as you prefer

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know to do it. I want to get dinamically values because every day that page will have new values. How can I associate td values with td data-odd values? please, give me an example. Thanks

Comment: something like `echo $e->innertext.' '.$td->attr['data-odd']`. But I am not a diviner. See your html and php code: the result depends on how it is formed, so the solution can be different. Read the basics of [html](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) and [php](http://www.w3schools.com/php/). Also see [simple_html_dom docs](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)